# Showing auth. errors in Django in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I'm new to Django. I have custom HTML form for login and sign up, so when I input wrong username or password my page just reloads. 
How can I put messages into HTML printing "wrong password" or "wrong username"?

My URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.logout_then_login, name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
    path('reset/', auth_views.password_reset, {'template_name': 'reset.html'}, name='reset'),  # здесь нужно менять на
    path('reset/done', auth_views.password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'password_reset_done.html'},
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
         {'template_name': 'password_reset_confirm.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.password_reset_complete, {'template_name': 'password_reset_complete.html'},
         name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

My custom views part:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activation'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Письмо для активации отправлено на вашу электронную почту.')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Part of login.html:

```
<form class="login-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}" id = "formlogin">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="имя пользователя"  for=<input type="text" name="username"
  maxlength="254" autofocus required id="id_username_log" />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="пароль" for=<input type="password" name="password"
  id="id_password_log" required />

  <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>

   <button type="submit">войти</button>

   <p class="message">Не зарегистрированны? <a href="#" id ="aregister-log" for="register-form">Создать аккаунт.</a></p>
   <p class="message">Забыли пароль? <a href="#" id ="arestore-log" for="reset-form">Востановить.</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be very useful to see your existing code.

Comment: edited my question and added code. Tx

Comment: You have added the view for signup. And the question you asked about how to display invalid credentials msg for login. Add the login view also.

Comment: I've just found the way how to solve this problem with login, just adding {% if form.errors %}
<p>Something is wrong</p>
{% endif %}